# What is a bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.6, the `base64.b64encode()` function requires "a bytes-like object, not `str`".

What is an example of a bytes-like object as opposed to a normal string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything that logically stores a sequence of bytes qualifies. That includes the actual `bytes` type, `bytearray`, `mmap.mmap`, `array.array('B')`, etc. `str` in Python 3 is a text type; the characters aren't stored in a specified encoding, so you can't use them as raw binary data directly; they must be `encode`-ed explicitly with a specific encoding.

For the technical definition, see the [Python 3 glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object):

> An object that supports the Buffer Protocol and can export a C-contiguous buffer. This includes all `bytes`, `bytearray`, and `array.array` objects, as well as many common `memoryview` objects. Bytes-like objects can be used for various operations that work with binary data; these include compression, saving to a binary file, and sending over a socket.
>
> Some operations need the binary data to be mutable. The documentation often refers to these as “read-write bytes-like objects”. Example mutable buffer objects include `bytearray` and a `memoryview` of a `bytearray`. Other operations require the binary data to be stored in immutable objects (“read-only bytes-like objects”); examples of these include `bytes` and a `memoryview` of a `bytes` object.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the string could be converted to bytes

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov: Added a note on that.

Comment: @ShadowRanger So, for example, if I was to use a json string in base64.b64encode(), how would I change the string to a bytes-like object?

Comment: @RayAntebioni: Typically JSON is represented as UTF-8, so you'd pass `jsonstring.encode('utf-8')`.